# run VBScripts in DosBox-X

Tags: vbscript, dosbox

Is it possible to run *.vbs from DosBox-X?

when I run cscript.exe - DosBox-X stops accepting any commands and needs to be restarted.

The main program is written for 16bit architecture, works through shared access, is launched in several instances by each user and send files via e-mail (vbs). Therefore, using Win emulation is not an option and will affect the startup time. And the developer himself refuses to reassemble on 32bit architecture. But now I need to use a program on Win10 x64 which does not support 16bit programs

Comment: The VBS script is launched from under DosBox-X. cscript.exe is located in the software folder. The version of cscript.exe is 5.6.0.8820 and I am not able to manually adjust the launch of the version from the software.

Running cscript.exe from the Windows console at least provides a prompt for the options to run. But when running cscript.exe in DosBox-X, no message is issued. It looks like I'm logged into the console software and it's waiting for commands to be entered, but nothing changes when I press any keys.

Comment: I think cscript.exe from WinXP and a simple VBS that creates a folder will be enough. The problem, in my opinion, is that VBS did not exist at the time of DOS, and maybe the solution does not exist

Comment: I installed Windows 98 in DosBox-X using the IMG file provide in the description of the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJtUdX_R6yE). Within the Windows 98 session, WScript and CScript worked fine. I doubt that you can use CScript directly in DosBox-X without running Windows 98. What do you want to script? Maybe there's another approach.

Comment: What I know is that scripts are created dynamically by the program itself and launched for execution. The script that I saw sends files via e-mail and then moves them between folders. The presence of other dynamically generated scripts or their absence is not yet known.
I also know that using NTVDM for Win10 under x32 architecture solves the problem, but installing this leads to the loss of some resources on new PCs, and there is no NTVDM solution from MS for more modern Win x64

Comment: You can also install Win10 32bit in VMWare Workstation Player.

Comment: As I said, it will take up too many resources, especially when running 3-5 instances or more. Also, each instance will take a long time to run. Okay, I'll leave it as it is